# How can i print numbers on single line

Tags: c, for-loop, numbers, printf

Silly doubt, how can i print numbers in sequence in C programming according to its variable value.
my Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{  
   int i,j,result;
   for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
   {
     for (j=i;j<=i;j++)
     {
       printf("%d\n%d",i,j+1);
     }
 }
}
```

getting output as

```
1
22
33
44
```

Expecting answer is:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

Comment: main() should return int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void main()
{  
   int i,j,result;
   for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
   {
     for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
     {
       printf("%d",i);
     }
     printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could help you. Note that in `C` array indexing starts at 0, not 1.

```
void main()
{  
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Array indexing may start at 0, but the OP isn't indexing arrays, so why mention it? The OP merely wants to print a sequence of numbers from 1 to 4.

Comment: Just a tweak use `for (i = 1; i <=4 ; ++i)` as the first row needs to be one and not zero

Comment: @EdHeal certainly. I just decided to notify the author.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{  
   int i,j,result;
   for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
   {
     for (j=i;j<=i;j++)
     {
       printf("%d",i);
     }
     printf("\n");
   }
}
```